# What are packages starting with libcommons-*?

Tags: package-management

I've just seen that many packages have a prefix `libcommons-*`:

```
moose@pc07:~$ apt-cache search libcommons-*

jsvc - wrapper to launch Java applications as daemons
libcommons-attributes-java - adds C#/.Net-style attributes to Java code
libcommons-attributes-java-doc - adds C#/.Net-style attributes to Java code - documentation
libcommons-beanutils-java - utility for manipulating JavaBeans
libcommons-beanutils-java-doc - Javadoc API for libcommons-beanutils-java
libcommons-cli-java - API for working with the command line arguments and options
libcommons-codec-java - encoder and decoders such as Base64 and hexadecimal codec
libcommons-codec-java-doc - encoder and decoders such as Base64 and hexadecimal codec - documentation
libcommons-collections-java - A set of abstract data type interfaces and implementations
libcommons-collections3-java - A set of abstract data type interfaces and implementations
libcommons-collections3-java-doc - Documentation for libcommons-collections3-java
libcommons-daemon-java - library to launch Java applications as daemons
libcommons-dbcp-java - Database Connection Pooling Services
libcommons-discovery-java - locates classes that implement a given Java interface
libcommons-discovery-java-doc - locates classes that implement a given Java interface (documentation)
libcommons-fileupload-java - File upload capability to your servlets and web applications
libcommons-httpclient-java - A Java(TM) library for creating HTTP clients
libcommons-httpclient-java-doc - Documentation for libcommons-httpclient-java
libcommons-io-java - Common useful IO related classes
libcommons-io-java-doc - Common useful IO related classes - documentation
libcommons-jxpath-java - manipulate javabean using XPath syntax
libcommons-jxpath-java-doc - Javadoc API for libcommons-jxpath-java
libcommons-lang-java - Extension of the java.lang package
libcommons-lang-java-doc - Extension of the java.lang package
libcommons-logging-java - commmon wrapper interface for several logging APIs
libcommons-logging-java-doc - commmon wrapper interface for several logging APIs (documentation)
libcommons-net-java - internet protocol suite Java library
libcommons-pool-java - pooling implementation for Java objects
libcommons-pool-java-doc - pooling implementation for Java objects - documentation
libcommons-vfs-java - Java API for accessing various filesystems
libcommons-vfs-java-doc - Java API for accessing various filesystems - documentation
libcommons-compress-java - Java API for working with tar, zip and bzip2 files
libcommons-configuration-java - Java based library providing a generic configuration interface
libcommons-configuration-java-doc - API Documentation for commons-configuration
libcommons-dbcp-java-doc - Database Connection Pooling Services - documentation
libcommons-digester-java - Rule based XML Java object mapping tool
libcommons-digester-java-doc - Rule based XML Java object mapping tool (documentation)
libcommons-el-java - Implementation of the JSP2.0 Expression Language interpreter
libcommons-javaflow-java - Java implementation of Continuations concept
libcommons-javaflow-java-doc - Java implementation of Continuations concept - documentation
libcommons-jci-eclipse-java - common Java interface for various compilers - Eclipse JDT
libcommons-jci-groovy-java - common Java interface for various compilers - Groovy
libcommons-jci-janino-java - common Java interface for various compilers - Janino
libcommons-jci-java - common Java interface for various compilers - Core and FAM
libcommons-jci-java-doc - common Java interface for various compilers - documentation
libcommons-jci-rhino-java - common Java interface for various compilers - Javascript
libcommons-jexl-java - expression language engine
libcommons-launcher-java - cross platform java application launcher
libcommons-math-java - Java lightweight mathematics and statistics components
libcommons-math-java-doc - Java lightweight mathematics and statistics components - documentation
libcommons-modeler-java - convenience library to use Java Management Extensions (JMX)
libcommons-modeler-java-doc - documentation and examples for Commons Modeler
libcommons-net2-java - internet protocol suite Java library
libcommons-net2-java-doc - internet protocol suite Java library
libcommons-openpgp-java - a common and simple interface for generating and verifying OpenPGP signatures
libcommons-openpgp-java-doc - a common and simple interface for generating and verifying OpenPGP signatures
libcommons-validator-java - ease and speed development and maintenance of validation rules
libcommons-validator-java-doc - API documentation for Commons Validator
libcommons-csv-java - a Java library for working with csv (comma separated values) files
libcommons-csv-java-doc - documentation for libcommons-csv-java
moose@pc07:~/Downloads/matrix-multiplication/Java$
```

All of them seem to be java-packages. But what else do they have in common?

(I've seen other prefixes for packages, how do I get to know their meaning by myself?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libcommons packages come from the [Apache Commons Project](http://commons.apache.org/), which is "an Apache project focused on all aspects of reusable Java components."

Usually Googling and/or following the dependency trail will tell you what a specific prefix means... :)